How do i get my rancher desktop / colima working?
This is the error I faced whenever I start with Rancher or colima.
For Rancher:

My virtual machine emulation is set to VZ and Rosetta Support is enable.

For colima:

I am installing via brew.

I am using Apple M3 Pro 36 GB and am on 14.4.1
Was wondering if anyone faced this issues before and what are the step to resolve this?
Error log:
'time="2024-04-05T09:19:11+08:00" level=info msg="[hostagent] Waiting for the essential requirement 1 of 4: \\"ssh\\""\n' +
    'time="2024-04-05T09:19:21+08:00" level=info msg="[hostagent] Waiting for the essential requirement 1 of 4: \\"ssh\\""\n' +
    'time="2024-04-05T09:19:31+08:00" level=info msg="[hostagent] Waiting for the essential requirement 1 of 4: \\"ssh\\""\n' +
    'time="2024-04-05T09:19:41+08:00" level=info msg="[hostagent] Waiting for the essential requirement 1 of 4: \\"ssh\\""\n' +
    'time="2024-04-05T09:19:41+08:00" level=info msg="[hostagent] Waiting for the essential requirement 2 of 4: \\"user session is ready for ssh\\""\n' +
    'time="2024-04-05T09:19:43+08:00" level=fatal msg="did not receive an event with the \\"running\\" status"\n',
  code: 1,
  [Symbol(child-process.command)]: '/Applications/Rancher Desktop.app/Contents/Resources/resources/darwin/lima/bin/limactl.ventura start --tty=false /Users/user1/Library/Application Support/rancher-desktop/lima/_config/0.yaml'
}

